# Get an list of multiple gameobjects that cross mouse line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting, gameobject

Actually I'm using this following code to detect the collision between the mouse and some object.

I want the code to capture multiple GameObjects (not only the first one, but the ones that are above) and store it in a List.

I looked about `Physics.RaycastAll` but I was a little confused about.

```
void Update () 
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    Ray ray =  Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit))
    {       
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            print (hit.transform.gameObject.name);          

        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: whats confusing about RaycastAll? there's even an example in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing confusing here. The only difference is that `Physics.Raycast` returns `true` or `false` if something is hit while `Physics.RaycastAll` returns array of `RaycastHit`. You just have to loop over that array of `RaycastHit`.

```
void Update()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    RaycastHit[] hit = Physics.RaycastAll(ray);

    for (int i = 0; i < hit.Length; i++)
    {
        if (hit[i].collider != null)
        {
            print(hit[i].transform.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**:

It is better to use `Physics.RaycastNonAlloc` instead of `Physics.RaycastAll` if you want to detect every Object hit. This will not allocate memory at-all especially when doing this in the `Update` function.

```
//Detect only 10. Can be changed to anything
RaycastHit[] results = new RaycastHit[10];

void Update()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    int hitCount = Physics.RaycastNonAlloc(ray, results);

    for (int i = 0; i < hitCount; i++)
    {
        if (results[i].collider != null)
        {
            print(results[i].transform.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will detect 10 objects max. You can increase it if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what you mean with not allocate memory by the way?

Comment: When your app request memory block from the OS. You are doing that every frame. That's like using creating new instance of a class in the update function but this is an array. By declaring the array outside the function and re-using it with the `Physics.RaycastNonAlloc` function, you are no longer allocation memory every time. Hence 'NonAlloc' keyword in that function. Coming from C++, that what we call it. Not sure if it's the-same with C#. Allocating memory each frame can cause GC to happen more often. This can freeze the game once in a while and ruin the 
 game experience.

Comment: Google "C# GC" if you don't know what GC is. If you are still confused, you can still search for "C# stack vs heap". That will likely help you.